# Do I need to call NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

You know how when you generate a class from an NSManagedObject, and it creates the CoreDataGeneratedAccessors for you...

```
@interface SomeManagedObject (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addBookmarkObject:(Bookmark *)value;
- (void)removeBookmarkObject:(Bookmark *)value;
- (void)addBookmark:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeBookmark:(NSSet *)values;
```

Well it seems redundant to have to call...

```
[someManagedObject removeBookmarkObject:myBookmark]
```

followed by ....

```
[managedObjectContext deleteObject:myBookmark]
```

Why doesn't the `removeBookmarkObject` make the call to `deleteObject` for me, if it is in fact needed?  Who would want to 'partially' delete an object from their database??

What am I missing about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you remove a `Bookmark` from the relationship, that doesn't necessarily mean you want it deleted: it might be perfectly valid to have a `Bookmark` which isn't (currently) related to any objects.  Suppose for example that `SomeManagedObject` was a `ShoppingBasket`, and `Bookmark` was `ShoppingItem` - would you want to delete a `ShoppingItem` from your shop, just because someone removed it from their `ShoppingBasket`?

But the reverse isn't true: if you delete a `Bookmark`, you mustn't leave any `Objects` related to it.  Bad things can (and generally will) happen.  Consequently, CoreData provides a mechanism (see "Relationship Delete Rules" in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1)) to automatically deal with related objects when you delete the source object.  So if the relationship is configured with your desired delete rule, you could just use:

```
[managedObjectContext deleteObject:myBookmark]
```

and CoreData will sort out the relationships.  (For example, if you specified a "nullify" delete rule, it would effectively call

```
[someManagedObject removeBookmarkObject:myBookmark]
```

for all the managedObjects related to `myBookmark`.)

Comment: Of course... what a head slapper.  It's hilarious how my brain already contained that knowledge, but totally failed to link the concepts together.  Thanks for filling in the missing connections... heh heh.

Answer (score 1):

The `removeBookmarkObject` breaks the relationship between a `SomeManagedObject` and a `Bookmark`. That does not imply deleting the `Bookmark`, because that's a different action that might or might not be related. It's not a "partial" delete, in fact it's not a delete of any kind. Whether that's useful really depends on your specific data and how you use it. Some reasons why you'd want to break the relationship might include:

- You plan on reassigning the `Bookmark` to a different instance of `SomeObject`.
- This relationship is optional, meaning that it's allowed to be nil, so it makes sense that sometimes you'd want to break a relationship without deleting either object.

Your specific app might use one or both or neither of those. Regardless, breaking a relationship and deleting an object are not the same thing, even "partially".